# MySQL is not working after resizing EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have configured separate MySQL Production server as EC2- [m2.xlarge](/questions/tagged/m2.xlarge). This is ubuntu server.MySQL is working perfectly from 3 years on this instance. 
But now I thought of downgrading a server because of less usage. When I stepped ahead to downgrade the server as [m1.medium](/questions/tagged/m1.medium) or [m1.small](/questions/tagged/m1.small) using [steps given by AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html) , I was able to resize it and started it with reassigning my original elastic IP, I found MySQL is now connecting from anywhere. 
I troubleshooted to connect MYSQL after resize as follows.
1. connected with ssh login on same instance and used command-line to connect.
2. Tried from outside(workbench) with same configuration..
3. Checked security groups assigned to instance. those are also in place..
4. **But when I again resize instance with original (m2.xlarge), It works** .

Still no success. any thing I missed after resizing process?

Comment: any logs from mysql ? do you have config to allocate more memory than you have from smaller instances ?

Comment: Mysql may be configured to access more memory than the smaller instances have.

Comment: you can denied to connect mysql from remotely using mysql.ini file which place in /etc/mysql folder